# Hosted web api is accessible through browser but not through application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api2, iis-8

I have hosted web api in iis 10.0 then accessing it's method through browser.
But the same method is not able to access through my MVC application.
Getting 404 Not found issue.

But when i run web api application i am able to access methods through application.

I did some googled and found some handlers that needs to be set in hosted web api web.config. But it also did not worked for me.

Below is my complete system.webserver tag used in web api web.config.

```html
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
   <remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" />
   <remove name="ApiURIs-ISAPI-Integrated-4.0" />
    <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" path="*." type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" preCondition="" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE" />
 <add name="ApiURIs-ISAPI-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
      <!--<add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS,XYZ" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS,XYZ" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS,XYZ" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />-->
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

Need help.

Comment: If it's accessible through your browser, then I would say there was an issue with the MVC application. I'd double check the URL/ scheme/ authentication etc.,

Comment: Hi Craig, Thanks for the response. I found it working now. The issue was in base url i used like http://localhost/applicationname but it should be like http://localhost/applicationname/. i was not using the last slash in url and that slash i was adding with the controller. I just added this slash in base url and removed from controller and it is started working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was doing some mistakes when passing the Web api url in application.

e.g: for web api Root url i was using like below:

http://localhost:25968

But it should be like : http://localhost:25968/

Last slash was missing due to it web api method was not accessing through application.